# sql issue with displaying the correct data

Tags: sql

I have these tables

**restaurant**

```
restaurantID
restaurantName
locationID
```

**location**

```
locationID
locationName
```

**dish**

```
dishID
DishName
restaurantID
price
```

**review**

```
reviewID
dishID
rating
```

Now I want to display these things:

```
`restaurantName`, `locationName`, #dishes from 1 specific restaurant, # of reviews per restaurant
```

But I'm a bit stuck with the SQL code.

I have this ATM:

```
SELECT 
    res.name, l.name, 
    (SELECT COUNT(dishID) FROM dish WHERE restaurantID = res.restaurantID),
    (SELECT COUNT(r.reviewID)) 
FROM 
    restaurant res, location l, review r, dish d 
WHERE 
    res.locationID = l.locationID 
    AND r.dishID = d.dishID 
    AND d.restaurantID = res.restaurantID 
GROUP BY 
    res.restaurantID
```

and it displays all what I want except for the restaurant that has no reviews.

But I want to have the count say 0 instead of not showing it at all.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard - stop using it

Comment: That statement is invalid because you are not grouping by `res.name` and `l.name`

Answer (score 0):

LEFT JOIN in used in sitations where you want to include results that find no matches in the table your joining into (ie this restaurant_id is not used by any dishes, or this dish matches no reviews; you still want it to have an row in the result after GROUPING).  However location is most likely mandatory, so use a regular join for it if you require this.

```
SELECT res.name, l.name, COUNT(dishID) as dish_count, COUNT(r.reviewID) as review_count 
FROM restaurant res
JOIN location l ON res.locationID = l.locationID 
LEFT JOIN dish d on d.restaurantID = res.restaurantID
LEFT JOIN review r on r.dishID = d.dishID 
GROUP BY res.restaurantID
```

Also this use case has no need for subqueries, when using joins you can eliminate these.

Comment: Try once more - i forgot to move the table aliasing into the JOINs, it is not supposed to also be in the FROM section either now.  Hopefully this makes sense as you see how we are giving specific instructions of how to join each step rather than using multiple tables in FROM and then using WHERE.